# Encountering an Invalid literal error whilst String Slicing

Tags: python-3.x

Okay so I am trying to write a program that can read lines of RLE and convert them into lines of ASCII Art, I am very new to Python so could anyone help me in understanding what I have done wrong in the code to create this error.

Thanks

[image: The code for this section]

[image: The python shell error screenshot]

Comment: Add code as text to question not as an image.

Comment: [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely, the question will be downvoted, for containing unnecessary screenshots.  By using screenshots, you are discouraging anyone from assisting you.  No one wants to retype your stuff, from a screenshot, and screenshots are often, not readable.

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that you're passing an invalid Integer Literal Value (0xa0) to your function int() in the block of code `for b in range (0,int(num))`

If you're going to pass a Hexadecimal value to the int function, you need to specify the numeric base (16) as the 2nd parameter of the int function `int("0xa0",16)`